# How to disable horizontal scrolling of SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

I need to disable SFSafariViewController horizontal scrolling. I want to fit the view respective of window. Is there any solution for the problem
?

Comment: Since SFSafariViewController is a subclass of `UIViewController`, you can search for its subviews until you find a `UIScrollView` and disable the horizontal scrolling of it, but I would consider using `WKWebView` instead.